# Use Nvidia Optimus GPU for all rendering on Windows

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, external-display

I have a laptop (XPS 9570) where the Thunderbolt and HDMI outputs are connected to the integrated Intel HD 630, but which also contains a Nvidia 1050 Ti. The performance on the laptop's built-in 4K display is mostly fine, but when connected to an external 5K monitor the issues of using integrated graphics become apparent. Basic tasks like text rendering in terminal windows become painfully slow, and any animations cause the mouse cursor to lag.

I believe without a multiplexer on the output it is impossible for the Nvidia card to drive the display directly, but is it possible to do *everything else* on the Nvidia card? I want Windows to behave as if the Nvidia card was the only card, as much as possible

It seems it is not possible to force dwm.exe to use the Nvidia card in the Nvidia Control Panel, is there any alternative?

I am fairly certain that if the above were possible it would solve my problem, as I can run (lo-fi) 3D applications at full 5K res through Optimus and get full 60 fps without tanking system performance. So there is at least enough memory bandwidth for passing the 5K framebuffer between GPUs, but perhaps not for the Intel GPU to do any rendering as well